# pause a container of a multi container pod in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, containers

I've a `pod` with two containers. I need to pause one of them because when it's getting error whole of `pod` will restart and the second container start all things from beginning. I need to suspend first container till second one do it's job. Can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define second one container as init container. Init containers are exactly like regular containers, except they always run to completion, each init container must complete successfully before the next one starts.

Here is an example:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: example
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app-container
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo The app is running! && sleep 3600']
  initContainers:
  - name: init-example
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', "until nslookup myservice.$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace).svc.cluster.local; do echo waiting for myservice; sleep 2; done"]
```

Take a look: [init-containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/).